# Is a header message used to notify peers of a new block?

Tags: relay

As far as I know, when we receive a new transaction or block, we send an INV message to all peers to inform them about it. If the peers want that data, they send us a GETDATA message. In several places (in BIP152 for example) I read and saw (picture below taken from BIP 152) that notification can also be done by sending a HEADER message? However, bitcoin wiki and all other sites say that this message is **a reply to a previously sent GETHEADERS message**.

[bitcoin.wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#headers):

> The headers packet returns block headers in response to a getheaders
> packet.

[bitcoindeveloper](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/p2p_networking.html#headers):

> The “headers” message sends block headers to a node which previously
> requested certain headers with a “getheaders” message. A headers
> message can be empty.

Can you explain to me whether the HEADER message is also used for notifying peers about new blocks, why and in which cases?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the introduction of BIP130 ("sendheaders"), a node can request that new block announcements are sent through a HEADERS message rather than through an INV. This avoids a roundtrip, in case the receiver first wants to verify the PoW of the header before downloading the actual block data.